# Check if date of post is yesterday

Tags: loop, date

In a loop, I want to display "Yesterday" if the date of the post(s) are dated from yesterday...

So here it goes:

```
<?php
    if( date('Yz') == get_the_time('Yz') ) {
        echo 'Today';
    } elseif ( date('') == get_the_time('') ) {
        echo  'Yesterday';
    } else {
        the_date();
    };
?>
```

Would you guys know the correct syntax on the elseif line?

Best regards,
Alex

---

Well, I can't answer my question yet because I'm a noob (not enough reputation). So here it is:

```
<?php $w_h = $w_d = 0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
    if ( date('Yz') == get_the_time('Yz') ) {
        if (!$w_d++) echo 'Today<br />';
    } elseif ( date('Yz')-1 == get_the_time('Yz') ) {
        if (!$w_h++) echo 'Yesterday<br />';
    } else {
        echo the_date();
    };
?>
```

Comment: I've added a community wiki version of your solution that you can accept so that the question is considered answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, one possible solution is something like:

```
<?php $w_h = $w_d = 0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
    if ( date('Yz') == get_the_time('Yz') ) {
        if (!$w_d++) echo 'Today<br />';
    } elseif ( date('Yz')-1 == get_the_time('Yz') ) {
        if (!$w_h++) echo 'Yesterday<br />';
    } else {
        echo the_date();
    };
?>
```